# Dockerized app works for Rails with PSQL but DB container not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm docker-izing a Rails app and there is a script in the app that runs a psql command.
This works fine outside of docker, but I'm when the docker container is running, the web app and the DB are different services.

So when the script in the Rails service has a psql command, it throws an error.  In this case, it throws "dropdb: command not found."

How do I get the the Rails app be able to run a script that contains a `psql` commend?

I think that I can solve this by adding the location of Postgres over to the  PATH. 
`ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin:$PATH`
But I think I'd need to get the path for that other service to do that.

I also see that it's possible to [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links) my two services, e.g.

```
  web:
    build: .
    links:
      - "db:database"
  db:
    image: postgres
```

What's the best practice for accessing the psql command from inside the container running rails?

Comment: Please include the relevant error you’re receiving.

Comment: I've updated the post.

Comment: Without seeing your `Dockerfile` it's hard to know, but keep in mind that you need to install `psql` in your `web` container and that you need to configure it to use the correct URL to your db container, e.g. `http://<pg_container_name>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Ruby container is missing the PostgreSQL client tools, you’ll have to find the appropriate package for whatever Linux distribution you’re using (e.g. Alpine’s [postgresql-client](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.8/main/s390x/postgresql-client)), and install it in the container running Rails. If there’s a “client” package available that’d be preferred, as the whole server is unneeded, but not all distributions may have that distinction. Altneratively, [PostgreSQL offers package repositories](https://www.postgresql.org/download/) for many distributions.

Comment: This... makes complete sense.  
I've added a step to my Dockerfile for installing the posgresql-client. 
That solves the problem I originally posted about, though I do get an error about connecting to the psql instance.
If there's some obvious config that I'm forgetting, let me know.  Otherwise, I can make a separate SO that addresses this other issue.

[dropdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?]

Comment: Probably should be a separate question, but probably you haven’t updated your `database.yml` to the correct hostname of the container (with docker-compose, usually just the service name).

Comment: Yeah, it was a different issue. I resolved it and then totally forgot about my SO question.  Thank you so much for responding.

Answer (score 3):

**First, I don't think that is a good idea to run migrations like you ask with the `psql` command. I would suggest to consider the following:**

I would recommend to use the native Rails library that can run your database migrations. This tool will use your own database credentials and will use the database driver provided by your application. I don't know if [this documentation from rubyonrails.org](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) will be enough but that's a good way to start.

> Migrations are a convenient way for you to alter your database in a structured and organized manner. You could edit fragments of SQL by hand but you would then be responsible for telling other developers that they need to go and run them. You’d also have to keep track of which changes need to be run against the production machines next time you deploy.
>
> https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/migrations.html

But anyway, I will answer your question because you can ask knowing the previous advice.

There are three steps to accomplish what you want.

First, that's correct, you can link containers like you said:

```
web:
  build: .
  links:
    - "db:db"
db:
  image: postgres
```

It means you can use "db" as hostname for your database in your web application.

The second one is to allow connections from your Rails container to the PostgreSQL container.

**Maybe this step is unecessary if the PostgreSQL is already accepting connections.**

In order to do this, you must edit the `pg_hba.conf` file in the PostgreSQL data directory. Why? Because you need to approve connection from outside the container, from you Rails application.

A `pg_hba.conf` file looks like this:

```
# Allow any user on the local system to connect to any database with
# any database user name using Unix-domain sockets (the default for local
# connections).
#
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     trust
```

You can follow the official documentation [here (for 9.6 version)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

Yours will look like:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             all                     md5
```

Or:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    database_name   username        docker_network          md5
```

Where database_name is the application database name, the username is the database username and the docker_network is the Docker network IP (for example `172.17.0.0/24`)

This will allow your Rails container to access the database.

If you don't want to loose this configuration after a container removal, take a look to the Docker volumes: [Volumes on docs.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) and [docker-compose volumes also on docs.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes).

Third step and last one, in order to run a `psql` command on another place than the PostgreSQL container, you need to have the tool installed in your container. That means you need to install it in your Docker image.

If your Rails image is based on an Ubuntu / Debian / Mint / ... you can do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libpq.so.5.4  /usr/lib/libpq.so  # adapt to the actual postgres version
```

The previous line were found [here (Install PostgreSQL Client driver)](https://gestinux.net/mediawiki/index.php/Install_Postgresql_client_driver).

You'll have to run your `psql` like this:

```
PGPASSWORD=<yourpass> psql -U username -H db < script.sql

# For manual usage, prompt the password
psql -U username -H db < script.sql
```

This is terribly insecure. That's why I recommended to avoid this solution at the begining of this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer.

Installing the postrgresql-client library cleard up the original problem I was expiencing.  
I'm still unable to actually run the script though.  Even when I've got the psql container's `pg_hba.conf` file configured to `host all all all trust`, I'm still not able to connect.  Those are the most permissive settings so I'm not sure exactly what else I need to be doing.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I don't have any `libqp` files in `/usr/lib/` so I was a bit confused about that part of the documentation.

Comment: What kind of error do you have? Is it a permission error?

Comment: No worries.  I figured it out.

Comment: Thanks again for such a thorough answer.